# Is char and int interchangeable for function arguments in C?

Tags: c++, c, char, int, alphanumeric

I wrote some code to verify a serial number is alpha numeric in C using `isalnum`.  I wrote the code assuming `isalnum` input is `char`.  Everything worked.  However, after reviewing the `isalnum` later, I see that it wants input as `int`.  Is my code okay the way it is should I change it?

If I do need to change, what would be the proper way?  Should I just declare an int and set it to the char and pass that to `isalnum`?  Is this considered bad programming practice?

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


bool VerifySerialNumber( char *serialNumber ) { 
int num;
char* charPtr = serialNumber;


if( strlen( serialNumber ) < 10 ) { 
    printf("The entered serial number seems incorrect.");
    printf("It's less than 10 characters.\n");
    return false;
}   

while( *charPtr != '\0' ) { 
    if( !isalnum(*charPtr) ) { 
    return false;
    }   
    *charPtr++;
}   
return true;
}


int main() {
char* str1 = "abcdABCD1234";
char* str2 = "abcdef##";
char* str3 = "abcdABCD1234$#";
bool result;

result = VerifySerialNumber( str1 );
printf("str= %s, result=%d\n\n", str1, result);

result = VerifySerialNumber( str2 );
printf("str= %s, result=%d\n\n", str2, result);

result = VerifySerialNumber( str3 );
printf("str= %s, result=%d\n\n", str3, result);
return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
str= abcdABCD1234, result=1

The entered serial number seems incorrect.It's less than 10 characters.
str= abcdef##, result=0

str= abcdABCD1234$#, result=0
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to change it. The compiler will implicitly convert your `char` to an `int` before passing it to `isalnum`. Functions like `isalnum` take `int` arguments because functions like `fgetc` return `int` values, which allows for special values like `EOF` to exist.

**Update:** As others have mentioned, be careful with negative values of your `char`. Your version of the C library *might* be implemented carefully so that negative values are handled without causing any run-time errors. For example, `glibc` (the GNU implementation of the standard C library) appears to handle negative numbers by adding 128 to the `int` argument.***** However, you won't always be able to count on having `isalnum` (or any of the other `<ctype.h>` functions) quietly handle negative numbers, so getting in the habit of not checking would be a very bad idea.

***** Technically, it's not adding 128 to the argument itself, but rather it appears to be using the argument as an index into an array, starting at index 128, such that passing in, say, `-57` would result in an access to index `71` of the array. The result is the same, though, since `array[-57+128]` and `(array+128)[-57]` point to the same location.

Comment: Thanks, @MikeHolt Is this considered bad programming practice or is it okay?

Comment: Do be careful about signed vs unsigned values.  If you only use characters in the range 0-127 then there is no problem.

Comment: @user1527227 No, it's not bad programming practice. Bad programming practice would be passing an `int` to a function that expects a `char` without taking precautions to ensure that the value isn't being truncated.

Answer (score 3):

*Usually* it is fine to pass a `char` value to a function that takes an `int`. It will be converted to the `int` with the same value. This isn't a bad practice.

*However*, there is a specific problem with `isalnum` and the other C functions for character classification and conversion. Here it is, from the ISO/IEC 9899:TC2 7.4/1 (emphasis mine):

> In all cases the argument is an `int`, **the value of which shall be
>   representable as an unsigned char** or shall equal the value of the
>   macro `EOF`. If the argument has any other value, the behavior is
>   undefined.

So, if `char` is a signed type (this is implementation-dependent), and if you encounter a `char` with negative value, then it will be converted to an `int` with negative value before passing it to the function. Negative numbers are not representable as `unsigned char`. The numbers representable as `unsigned char` are `0` to `UCHAR_MAX`. So you have undefined behavior if you pass in any negative value other than whatever `EOF` happens to be.

For this reason, you should write your code like this in C:

```
if( !isalnum((unsigned char)*charPtr) )
```

or in C++ you might prefer:

```
if( !isalnum(static_cast<unsigned char>(*charPtr)) )
```

The point is worth learning because at first encounter it seems absurd: *do not pass a `char` to the character functions*.

Alternatively, in C++ there is a two-argument version of `isalnum` in the header `<locale>`. This function (and its friends) do take a `char` as input, so you don't have to worry about negative values. You will be astonished to learn that the second argument is a locale ;-)